# can't query over ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField)

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have the following model

```
class Skill(EmbeddedDocument):
   name =  StringField(required = True)
   level = IntField(required = True)

class Agent(Document):
   name = StringField(required = True)
   email = EmailField(required = True, unique = True)
   skills = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Skill))
```

I want to search for the Agents that have skills with (name = "computer skills and level >5)

I have wrote the following query:

```
 Agent.objects.filter(name='ashraf',  skills__level__gt=5,skills__name="Computer Skills")
```

If an Agent have skill named "Computer skills" with level = 3 and also have a skill named "English skills" with level = 10 this Agent will be in the query result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do an `$elemMatch`[1] query and there is no inbuilt support for it in mongoengine at this time.  You'd have to do a **raw** query like so:

```
Agent.objects.filter(
    name='ashraf',  
    __raw__={"skills": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "level": {"$gt": 5}, 
            "name": "Computer Skills"
        }
    }}
)
```

[1] http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch

Answer (score 0):

I don't use python driver, but the general Mongo syntax for what you're trying to accomplish is this....

```
db.agent.find({name:'ashraf', 'skills.name' : "computer skills", level:{ $gt: 5}})
```

Comment: I want to query on the Agent that have skill name x and level y for the this skill  
note:- the Agent have list of skills each with name and level

Comment: I understand, the query I provided conforms to your requirements, unless I'm missing something...it querys on agent name, skill name, and skill level, remove `name:'ashraf'` from my example and you'll get all the agents that have skill x and skill level y