# Changing a value in a listfield of embedded documents on MongoEngine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, database

I am learning how to use MongoEngine and MongoDB, and I know how to query over Listfield(EmbeddedDocumentField) from this question:

[can't query over ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241408/cant-query-over-listfieldembeddeddocumentfield)

Sort of nasty. Kind of wish there was something easier than that.

I know how to change the name of an agent using the same example from the link:

```
Agent.objects(name="Brenna Li").update_one(set__name="Brenna Smith")
```

But how can I change a value inside an embedded document in a listfield? For example, what is the code I need to change Brenna Li's skill level in C++ from a 6 to a 8 and her skill level in Java from 4 to a 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [positional operator $](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update) or `S` in mongoengine (so it can be used as a keyword argument).  However, you can only update a single match at a time.  Making it impossible to update both the Java and C++ levels in a single query - without replacing the whole `Skills` list (which wouldnt be very safe).

To do it in two queries you could do something like:

```
    class Skill(EmbeddedDocument):
       name =  StringField(required = True)
       level = IntField(required = True)

    class Agent(Document):
       name = StringField(required = True)
       email = EmailField(required = True, unique = True)
       skills = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Skill))

    Agent.drop_collection()

    Agent(name="Brenna Li", email="br@example.com",
          skills=[Skill(name="Java", level=2),
                  Skill(name="Surfing", level=6),
                  Skill(name="c++", level=4)]).save()

    Agent.objects.filter(name="Brenna Li", skills__name="Java").update(set__name="Brenna Smith", inc__skills__S__level=1)
    Agent.objects.filter(name="Brenna Smith", skills__name="c++").update(inc__skills__S__level=1)
```

Comment: What if the class Skill contained another attribute which was also a ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField)? How would I go about changing a value that is nested that deeply?